# Chrome cancels Angular 2 request

Tags: google-chrome, angular

I am writing an Angular 2 app that calls to a PHP api on localhost.
The HTML in **login.component.html** is as follows:

```
<form name="loginForm" class="loginForm">

    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="model.email" size="65">

    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" class="input" size="20">

    <button tabindex="12" class="btn-full submit" (click)="attemptLogin()">Log In</button>
</form>
```

Then **login.component.ts** has the attemptLogin() function:

```
attemptLogin(){
    this.identityService.attemptLogin(this.model).subscribe(
        result => {
            if(result.isauthenticated){
                console.log('Successful Auth');
            }else {
                console.log('Failed Auth');
            }
        }, 
        err => {
            console.log(err);
        });  
}
```

And then in **identityService.ts** I have:

```
attemptLogin(credentials: Credentials): Observable<Authorization> {

    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let bodyString = JSON.stringify(credentials); 


    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/login', bodyString, options)
        .map((res:Response) => res.json())
        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
}
```

I made sure the backend php is working and returning a valid response. My issue is that chrome cancels the request, IE the same, but firefox does work and successfully returns the response.
This worked at some point, I updated chrome recently, which might have something to do with it. I also made sure this is not a CORS issue, since it really worked in chrome before the update, and also works fine with Mozilla.
Here is the Chrome response:

[image]

And finally the cancelled request header:
[image]

thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My initial guess is that you need to add the `type="button"` attribute/value to your button tag. The default behavior of a button tag in Chrome is to submit the form, which is cancelling your request (when the *browser* posts the form back to itself).

For example:

```
<!-- Added button 'type' attribute/value -->
<button type="button" tabindex="12"...
```

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

Quoted from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp):

> **Tip**: Always specify the type attribute for a `<button>` element. Different browsers use different default types for the `<button>`
>   element.

Comment: It worked! I can't believe it but it did :) Thanks Steve

Comment: No problem.  Glad that I could help!

Comment: Took ages to land up here. This answer is a life saver :)